# Jekyll sitemap exclude not working

Tags: css, jekyll

I wonder why `main.css` still appears in my final `sitemap.xml`.
I'm not using any sitemap plugin `in _config.yml`.

In `/sitemap.xml`'s code, it says:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% unless page.sitemap.exclude == "yes" %}
```

So I added following on top of `/css/main.scss`:

```
---

sitemap:
exclude: yes

---
```

Still, `main.css` appears in `/_site/sitemap.xml`

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the yaml expression `page.sitemap.exclude`, `exclude` is a child of `sitemap`.

The correct indentation to reflect this parenthood, is :

```
---
sitemap:
  exclude: "yes"
---
```

Comment: Sorry, you also need to make exclude as a string by adding double quotes. With no double quotes it is seen as a boolean. I've edited my answer.

Comment: So maybe you can approve my answer.

Comment: any updates? this clearly doesn't work anymore. i'm also having issues with the updated instructions, from https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The question was about a custom use of a custom front matter value. The default sitemap plugins templates uses `sitemap: false` flag.

Comment: oh, ok. that makes sense now! sorry. but still, `sitemap: false` doesn't work for me (under https://ahoxus.org/pt/propostas/naturala/ source and sitemap are there if you wanna see it). still trying to figure out why. does it work for you?

Comment: Having a look at your generated **_site/sitemap.xml** indicates that everything is working fine. Naturala page is not present.

Comment: oh, ok... thanks for looking into it! i was hoping it would not appear under `/sitemap` but that explains something, might help me to get to the point i wanted. thanks again! 

Answer (score 0):

I work around this in my `sitemap.xml` with an extra check for `page.title`:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
{% if page.title %}
<url>
    <loc>{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}</loc>
</url>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```